# Shell Prompt Customization?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh, prompt

I have used oh_my_zsh (and tinkered with bash_it) on multiple systems and have generally been happy with it, though I hate it's auto-correction feature and generally turn it off.

My usual shell is zsh and I really want just three things from my prompt:

1. Current directory/or pwd.
2. Git status and branch.
3. Color output from ls (on the ls command, not in the prompt).

The rest is just bling and is often irritating.

By using these shell scripts I am paying too much in cpu cycles for what I want.

Any suggestions, either with using these scripts or as a separate shell script. I am OK with either zsh or bash.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want "colour output from ls" in your prompt?...

Comment: You could extract the for you relevant parts from the zsh config of grml (http://grml.org/zsh/ ).

Comment: Not really in the prompt but I do want color output from ls. I guess it is not so much a prompt issue but I know it does involve some shell scripting.

Comment: Also asked on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/q/114227/10127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have colored output from ls, use the alias `ls='ls --color=always'`.
You can enable this with

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
```

As for having your current directory in your prompt:

```
PROMPT='%~'
```

To add git status to you prompt, take a look at [this](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/28/zsh-git-status.html).

Comment: --color=auto should of course DTRT if the detection works.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this script from git/contrib](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) with bash. It gives me git branch and autocompletion as well. git status can be hacked in pretty easily too, from what I understand.